# Mail Server and Tomcat server on two separate machines with one domain name

Tags: tomcat, mail-server, domain-name, dedicated-server

*Warning: This question may look a bit stupid but I really need someone to answer it as precisely as possible. I hope my questions are clear enough. Thanks.*

1) I need a dedicated server (running Debian with a Tomcat server and `N` Webapps `webapp1`, `webapp2`, ..., `webappN`).

I would like to use the domain name `foo.com`

Thus, the base URL for the pages of `webapp1` will be: `http://foo.com/webapp1/`

The base URL for the pages of `webapp2` will be: `http://foo.com/webapp2/`

...

The base URL for the pages of `webappN` will be: `http://foo.com/webappN/`

2) I also need several email addresses for exactly the same domain name `foo.com`

For example: `john@foo.com`, `daniel@foo.com`, ...

BUT I DO NOT want to install, configure and manage a Mail Server on the dedicated server.

So here is my question; is it possible to have:

- on the one hand, the dedicated server which runs a Tomcat server serving the URLs `http://foo.com/webappI/ (I = 1, 2, ..., N)`
- on the other hand, another (physically distinct) machine which runs a Mail Server which manages the email addresses of the form `<person>@foo.com`
  For example, the machine running the Mail Server would be machine administered by a hosting service provider.

If it is possible, can you explain how it works?

Comment: on a single http port u can't run more than one tomcat...to run more than one tomcat u need to change the port no for each tomcat.

Comment: This is question of correct DNS configuration. You have to set an `A` and/or `CNAME` record for `foo.com` domain, with the IP address of your Tomcat server, and an `MX` record for the same domain, with the IP address of the provider's mail-server machine.